# Module not found: Can't resolve 'zlib_bindings' in next.js when trying to connect to mariadb database

Tags: next.js, mariadb

When i try to connect to my mariadb database on my next.js server using the [mariadb](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mariadb) npm module i get a error:

```
Module not found: Can't resolve './zlib_bindings'

Import trace for requested module:
./node_modules/mariadb/lib/io/compression-input-stream.js
./node_modules/mariadb/lib/connection.js
./node_modules/mariadb/promise.js
./pages/db.js

https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/module-not-found
```

[image error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XPK7W.png)

Code:

```
const pool = mariadb.createPool({host: process.env.DB_HOST, user: process.env.DB_USER, connectionLimit: 5});

async function asyncFunction() {
  let conn;
  try {

    conn = await pool.getConnection();
    const rows = await conn.query("SHOW DATABASES;");
  console.log(rows);
  console.log("test");
    // rows: [ {val: 1}, meta: ... ]

  } finally {
    if (conn) conn.release(); //release to pool
  }
}

export default function db() {
  return <p>Hello, World!</p>
}
```

Comment: You can only run that code on a Node.js environment (server-side), not in the browser (client-side).

Comment: oh i guess i forgot to put it in a server side function, thanks.